# Routing specific websites through a VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a Windows VM connected to VPN, and I want to route traffic on the host machine that requires access through VPN to be routed through the VM

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You would configure this in the same way as you would if the machine wasn’t a VM.

Comment: How would you do that?